# Site to site active directory for hyperv replication

Tags: active-directory, vpn

We have two dedicated servers across two different sites. They host hyper v virtual machines for email hosting etc. I'd like to have hyper v do replication between them and so I have a copy elsewhere, if something goes wrong re-route traffic to the other server (that side of it, i.e. the ip re route is all setup)
However, the problem is how do I get the active directories talking to each other. Site to site vpn is out of the question I belive as I cannot add hardware either side to do the connection. I'm not sure software VPN will suffice here?
The setup:

Hypervisor 01 - Windows server datacentre 2012

- 5x virtual machines running
- Active Directory running on the
  hypervisor

Hypervisor 02 - Windows server datacentre 2012 Nothing running yet (I wish to add this to the hypervisor 01 active directory to use hyper v's built in replication options. i believe it requires the use of AD to keep everything in sync nicely.
What do you guys recommend?
Tom

Comment: Hyper-V Replica doesn't require the Hyper-V hosts to be in the same AD domain. It doesn't even require that they be domain members to begin with.

Comment: I was warned that the vms flap when not in AD, get stuck in a loop when reverting over